# How to check a gate in a controller with Gate::authorize?

Tags: laravel

I define a gate in my auth service provider boot method like so:

```
Gate::define('test', function (User $user) {
        return false;
});
```

For this example, it will not allow anything through.

In my controller index method I have:

```
Gate::authorize('test');
```

Yet, nothing happens. I've tried the example:

```
if (! Gate::allows('test')) {
        abort(403);
    }
```

The above example, works as expected with a 403 response, but I thought `Gate::authorize('test')` is a helper method that does pretty much the same thing? Why is it not working?

Comment: `Gate::authorize('test')` throws `\Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException` if failed

Comment: But nothing is being throwed?

Comment: laravel version?

Comment: Yes latest laravel version - 8.12

Comment: `$result = Gate::authorize('test')` check the `$result` content

Comment: `Gate::athorize()` is almost the same, except it throws an `AuthorizationException` if it fails. Using `Gate::allows()` allows you to define what logic is executed, such as in your example.

Did you include the `$this->registerPolicies()` in your Auth Service Provider?

Comment: The result is Illuminate\Auth\Access\Response {#1558 ▼
  #allowed: true
  #message: null
  #code: null
}

Comment: $this->registerPolicies() is in my boot method of service provider

Comment: something strange, ur comment says the result is true